# Remove element conflicts to keep most elements possible

Tags: algorithms

*I originally wanted to post this to Stack Overflow, but then I realized it's not really code, but just an algorithm, so I decided to switch here. I hope I understood the purpose of this site correctly.*

---

I have a set of things, which can "conflict" with some of the others. What I'd like to do is to **eliminate some of them to remove all conflicts, while keeping as many items as possible**.

I start with a half matrix of which items conflict (marked with `#`, item can't conflict with itself):
*(e.g. C conflicts with B and D)*

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
A
B  #
C  .  #
D  #  #  #
E  #  .  .  .
F  .  .  .  #  .
```

Now my idea was to create an array of current number of collisions for each item, and iteratively keep removing those with most collisions. In first round, it is item `D`, so I mark it deleted (`null`), and then I also decrease the number of collisions for `A, B, C, F`, which it was colliding with.

Full procedure of this algorithm:

```
 A     B  C     D     E  F
[3,    3, 2,    4,    1, 1] - remove D, decrement A,B,C,F
[2,    2, 1, null,    1, 0] - now there are 2 options, I choose to remove B (decr. A,C)
[1, null, 0, null,    1, 0] - again options, choose to remove E
[0, null, 0, null, null, 0] - done
```

However, I'm not sure if this always gives the best possible solution (the most items remain). So: **does this always keep as many elements as possible**, and **if not, is there any algorithm that guarantees that**? Should there be just some additional logic in the case there are more options?

---

Some programming stuff:

- I don't care about performance that much, it's going to run on sets of at most around 100 items. What I care about is result that really includes as many items as possible.
- I would love to hook some additional logic when there are multiple possibilities: the elements have sizes, so I'd like to keep biggest total sum. However, since the item sizes will be relatively close to each other and quite big (for any 3 element sizes, $x + y \gg z$), the number of remained elements is the more important part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's formulate this with a graph $(V,E)$:

- your "things" will be the nodes $V$
- whenever there's a conflict between two things, we put an edge $e \in E$ between the corresponding nodes.

What you're trying to find is a set $S \subset V$ of nodes, so that when removing it, your graph has no edge anymore. In other terms, every edge in the first graph has to have at least one end that is part of $S$.

This problem is known as the [vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover), which is one of the classic NP-complete problems. This means that there is no known optimal algorithm that runs in polynomial time. So even your set size of $100$ might be a problem for exponential algorithms (yet, you can still try to run one ; sometimes it actually runs fast). But for this problem, there are approximation algorithms, which are guaranteed to give a solution within a certain bound of the optimal solution. You can look in this direction.